# Access Y coordinate of UIButton?

Tags: swift, xcode, uibutton

I have a title screen of a game where hard mode is not unlocked until later. Until the player reaches a score of 50, the hard button on the title screen is "covered" by a UILabel (which is the button but grayed out). In my viewdidload, I need to set the y coordinate of the label to the y coordinate of the UIButton (the hard button), so that it can only show if the prerequisites are cleared. I set it manually using the y coordinate in the storyboard, but this doesn't work for the different screen sizes. This is my code:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    // Grays out the Hard Button if high score is less than 50
    if highScore >= 50 {
        hardButtonCover.frame.origin.y = 100000
    }
    else{
        hardButtonCover.frame.origin.y = 5
    }
}
```

So instead of the part "hardButtonCover.frame.origin.y = 5", I need it to somehow be "hardButtonCover.frame.origin.y = hardButton.frame.origin.y", where hardButton is a UIButton, and the hardButtonCover will cover the UIButton completely upon loading.

Thank you to everyone in advance.

Comment: What happens when you use `hardButtonCover.frame.origin.y = hardButton.frame.origin.y`? because that does look correct to me

Comment: In The Story Board, place the buttonCover over the UIButton.  You can center it using AutoLayout, so it will always center on the button regardless of device.  Then when the player should access the Hard Button set hardButtonCover.isHidden = true.  The isHidden property may be useful here.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use autolayout contraints       . and then make outlet of a consraint you you want to update on some condition. I think this should work and a better way to impliment it. if you wanna do this in that way , then i can help you if needed.